# how to resume the wget process?

Tags: wget

I accidentally closed the terminal while running a `wget` process to download a website. It has been 2 days since I started the wget process, so I don't know the process' status.

Yesterday the traffic was high and today the traffic is low. It looks like the wget process is finished, but on `top`, it still shows wget running. This is confusing.

```
19133 root      15   0  751m 746m 1416 S  1.0 37.0  48:18.77 wget
```

How do I resume the wget process to see the status?

Comment: what command did you ran at the time along with wget ?

Comment: `wget -k -m -r -q -t 1 http://www.web.com/`

Answer (score 13):

If the web server you were downloading from supports resuming connections, then you can kill the wget process and restart it with the `-c` command (for continue).  It won't continue if it finds it's already downloaded the entire file contents, otherwise it will resume from where it left off.

Comment: using `pkill -9 wget` ?

Comment: Right.  Then the same wget command with options you typed earlier with a `-c` added.  I've tried this with large downloads, stopped them and restarted.  It should work with recursive downloads as well.